# Chromecast Receiver Application Fails to Launch With Error Code 15

Tags: javascript, android, chromecast

While trying to launch a custom receiver application, onApplicationConnectionFailed is occasionally called with Error Code 15. Other times, the application launches successfully, but onApplicationConnected is never called.

I thought maybe it was my sender application code, but I switched all connection logic to now use the Cast Companion Library, and I'm still seeing the same issues.

I've loaded the receiver application in a browser, and I'm not seeing any javascript errors.

Here is the receiver application code for window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
    window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
    console.log('Starting Receiver Manager');

    // initialize the CastReceiverManager with an application status message
    window.castReceiverManager.start({statusText: "Application is starting"});

    // handler for the 'ready' event
    castReceiverManager.onReady = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Ready event: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
      window.castReceiverManager.setApplicationState("Application status is ready...");
    };

    // handler for 'senderconnected' event
    castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Sender Connected event: ' + event.data);
      console.log(window.castReceiverManager.getSender(event.data).userAgent);

    };

    // handler for 'senderdisconnected' event
    castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
      if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
        window.close();
      }
    };

    // handler for 'systemvolumechanged' event
    castReceiverManager.onSystemVolumeChanged = function(event) {
      console.log('Received System Volume Changed event: ' + event.data['level'] + ' ' +
          event.data['muted']);
    };

    // create a CastMessageBus to handle messages for a custom namespace
    window.messageBus =
      window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
          'urn:x-cast:com.wolfgang.chromecasttest.app');

    // handler for the CastMessageBus message event
    window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
      console.log('Message [' + event.senderId + ']: ' + event.data);
      // display the message from the sender
      var sentMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if(sentMessage.command == 'MESSAGE'){
        displayText(sentMessage.payload);
        window.messageBus.send(event.senderId, sentMessage.payload);
      } else if(sentMessage.command == 'AUDIO_UPDATE'){
        console.log('GOT BASE64 AUDIO: ' + sentMessage.payload);
        translateAudio(sentMessage.payload);
        window.messageBus.send(event.senderId, 'Audio Update Received');
      } else if(sentMessage.command == 'IPUPDATE'){
        deviceIP = sentMessage.payload;
        reloadImage();
      } else{
        window.messageBus.send(event.senderId, 'Invalid Message Sent');
      }
      // inform all senders on the CastMessageBus of the incoming message event
      // sender message listener will be invoked

    }


    console.log('Receiver Manager started');



  };
```

Comment: Error 15 indicates a timeout. Are you sure you don't have any network issues on your side? On the receiver, did you turn on the logging?

Comment: To follow up, @AliNaddaf. you were correct. I was never able to track down exactly what the issue was, but moving from an internal to an external server resolved the issue.